# Basic GUI setToolTipText

Tags: java

I am trying to create a simple JFrame with a text tip on hover.
The JFrame appears to appear well, however, the text tip never pops up. Can anyone help me troubleshoot what might be the problem? I am not getting any errors.

Main Class

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class PracticeMain {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Sub obj = new Sub();

        obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        obj.setSize(275,150);
        obj.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Sub Class

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Sub extends JFrame{

    private JLabel item1;

        public Sub(){
        //adds title
        super("MY TITLE");

        //gives us the default layout
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        item1 = new JLabel("This is a sentence");
        item1.setToolTipText("help tip");

        add(item1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you hover the mouse over the label?

Comment: Yes, I hover the mouse over the "This is a sentence" label.

Comment: @MHZ, it works on my side. Maybe you should specify JRE and OS information. Or just wait for tool tip a little bit more:)

Comment: Your right -_-  Why is it so slow? The machine I am working on is relatively fast.

Comment: You can do `ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setInitialDelay(0);` make it faster. Note: It will for all the components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've compiled it and tooltip text appears. You should wait for about two seconds for it to show.

Comment: Gosh, you're right, it took me about 4sec! Why is it so darn slow?! What if I wanted to create legitimate GUI program using java, would it be that slow for the end user?